# 'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'get_reverse_joining_fields'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to retrieve similar posts by tag. spent hours trying to fix this issues but couldn't. Thank you for any help
here is my views.py

````
def post_detail(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, 
                             status=Post.Status.PUBLISH, 
                             id=id)
    post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__in = post_tags_ids).exclude(id=post.id)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags = Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags', '-pblish')[:4]
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    form = commentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', context={"post":post, 
                                                             'comments':comments, 
                                                             'form':form,
                                                             'similar_posts':similar_posts}) ```
The error message i get is 
*'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'get_reverse_joining_fields'*
````

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, updating taggit to the latest version should work.

```
pip install --upgrade django-taggit
```